# Copy from loop to variable c

Tags: c, loops

I am using this code to read through a buffer of results. My question is simply how do I copy the C value which displays a character of hex into a new string which I can printf out at the end of the for loop.

```c
for (long i=1; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)  //for all chars in string
{
     unsigned char c = buffer[i];

     switch (Format)
     {
          case 2:         //hex
          printf("%02x",c);
          break;
          case 1:         //asc
          printf("%c",c); // want to copy c to a varriable  byte by byte 
          break;
     }  //end of switch format
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to `printf` to a string? That can be done with `snprintf`. Though I don't see why you'd want to use that function in `case 1`, since you already have a character.

Comment: This is looping i need to save the charactors into a string as the original buffer is corrupted with illegal charactors in the first and last 20 positions. I need to copy the correct bytes to a new var. As printf will not work on buffer due to these characters.

Comment: Sprintf f crashes in loop for example sprintf(newvar,"%c",c);

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  long i;
  int Format = 2;
  char buffer[20] = "Test string";
  char result[60] = "";
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)  //for all chars in string
  {
    unsigned char c = buffer[i];
    char* printf_format;
    switch (Format) {
      case 2:         //hex
        printf_format = "%02x";
      break;
      case 1:         //asc
        printf_format = "%c";
      break;
    }  //end of switch format
    sprintf(result + strlen(result), printf_format, c);
  } 
  printf("result: %s\n", result); 

}
```

Here `result + strlen(result)` is a pointer to the end of the string. So `sprintf` will be write to the end. Note that you must figure out how long the output string can be and allocate enough memory to hold it. Note also that first value of `i` in your loop should be 0 instead of 1.

Comment: that works wonderful words cant express how grateful I am being messing around with this since 9 this morning. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

```
char *printit(char *buffer, long buflen)
{
   char out[512];
   int offset=0;

   for (long i=1; i<buflen; i++)
   {
     int l = snprintf(out+offset, sizeof(out)-offset, Format==1?"%c":"%02x", buffer[i]);
     if (l > sizeof(out)-offset)
     {
       fprintf(stderr, "Output buffer insufficiently large\n");
       return(NULL);
     }
     offset += l-1;
   }
   return(strdup(out));
 }
```

Note in your question code, you are skipping the first character of buffer.  isprint() might be a better function that your mysterious Format variable.